# Include only post type and post on wordpress search

Tags: wordpress, search, custom-post-type

```
//Exclude pages from WordPress Search
if (!is_admin()) {
function wpb_search_filter($query) {
if ($query->is_search) {
$query->set('post_type', 'post');
}
return $query;
}
add_filter('pre_get_posts','wpb_search_filter');
}
```

My question is there: How can I include in my query multiple post type and the post.
I want to excude pages from Wordpress search.

Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 0):

```
//Exclude pages from WordPress Search
if (!is_admin()) {
function wpb_search_filter($query) {
if ($query->is_search) {
$query->set('post_type', ['post', 'portfolio']);
}
return $query;
}
add_filter('pre_get_posts','wpb_search_filter');
}
```

It works ;p